# Find all functions $ \mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Z} $ such that $f(a-b+f(b))=f(a)+f(b)$

Tags: functional-equations

I found this problem in an old book of math, here is my try:

$$P(a;a) \mapsto ff(a)=2f(a)$$
$$P(a;f(b)) \mapsto f(a+f(b))=f(a)+2f(b)$$
$$P(0;b) \mapsto f(0)=0$$
$$P(0;b) \mapsto f(f(b)-b)=f(b)...(1)$$
$$P(b-f(b);b)\mapsto f(b-f(b))=-f(b)..(2)$$
From (1) and (2), f is odd

I really would be thankful if someone could give me the full solution please, thanks in advance !

Comment: I believe there is a typo on the third line: shouldn't it start $P(0;0)$?

Comment: @Maxwol This is a nice functional equation, but your post is poorly written. To avoid it being downvoted/closed, could you improve it so that it matches the [quality guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) ?

Comment: Could you help me to prove it plz

Comment: To start with, you should probably write full sentences to : - explain briefly where the equation comes from ;  - detail the reasoning in (what I believe to be) your proof attempt ; - clearly ask your question (do you want us to check your proof, give a hint, provide a full solution, etc.). You can take a look at what the OP [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651784/how-prove-there-is-no-continuous-functions-f0-1-to-mathbb-r-such-that-f) looks like.

Answer (score 3):

As you've seen, by setting $a=b$ we have

$$
f(f(a))=f(a-b+f(b))=f(a)+f(b)=2f(a)
$$

And by setting $b=f(b')$ for some $b'\in\mathbb Z$ we get (by using the last result)

$$
f(a+f(b'))=f(a-b+f(b))=f(a)+f(b)=f(a)+f(f(b'))=f(a)+2f(b')
$$

And by setting $a=0$ we get

$$
2f(b')=f(f(b'))=f(0)+2f(b')
$$

Thus $f(0)=0$.

Now let $a=f(1)$, we will show that $f(n)=na$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, first by induction to show it for all $n\geq 0$:

- The base case is $f(0)=0=0a$
- Now suppose $f(n)=na$ for some $0\leq n\in\mathbb Z$, then we have
  $$
  f(n+1)+na=f(n+1)+f(n)=f(n+1-n+f(n))=f(1+f(n))=f(1)+2f(n)=a+2na
  $$
  So $f(n+1)=(n+1)a$.

Finally, for all $0 > n\in\mathbb Z$ we have that $-n, -2n$ are positive so
$$f(n)-4na=f(n)+2f(-2n)=f(n+f(-2n))=f((-n)-(-2n)+f(-2n))=f(-n)+f(-2n)=-na-2na=-3na$$
And we get $f(n)=na$.

Now to show $a\in\{0,2\}$, note that we have:
$$
a^2=f(a)=f(f(1))=2f(1)=2a
$$